# Scrapear clases

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, scraping

Estoy intentando scrapear la clase con el siguiente codigo:

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
url="https://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/poland/ekstraklasa/lks-lodz-lechia-gdansk/fgQY4hAD/"
browser.get(url)

element = browser.find_elements_by_class_name("table-main__detail-odds--hasarchive")

browser.close()
```

Al ejecutar ese codigo no muestra ningun error pero al cambiar la clase por

```
element = browser.find_elements_by_class_name("data-odd")
```

Devuelve una lista vacía, mi objetivo es obtener lo señalado en la imagen
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tambien me pregunto si seria mas sencillo coger todos estos datos con un xpath, de esta forma he obtenido las "data-odds" junto con los nombres pero no las "data-opening-odd".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una manera fácil de obtener la tabla con los datos que deseas, es localizar la tabla a traves de [CSS_SELECTOR](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html).

¿Cómo obtener el selector?

De la misma manera que accediste a inspeccionar elementos, te posicionas por ejemplo en el primer elemento de la tabla y le das click derecho, `Copy > Copy selector`, en esta página obtenemos `#sortable-1 > tbody > tr:nth-child(1)`. Si hacemos `browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#sortable-1 > tbody > tr:nth-child(1)')`, solo nos devuelve la primer "row" de la tabla, porque es lo que hemos solicitado.

¿Y qué pasa si quitamos esa "pseudo clase" `nth-child`?

Podemos ver que nos devuelve la tabla completa, entonces quiere decir que `nth-child(1)` , estaba especificando que solo va a mostrar el primer elemento. Pues ahora intentemos llevarlo a la práctica, pero tener en cuenta que si queremos todos los elementos tenemos que usar find_element**s**.

Ahora vamos a tratar de replicar la tabla utilizando `pandas`.

```
tbody = browser.find_element_by_tag_name('tbody')

my_list = []
for tr in tbody.find_elements_by_css_selector('#sortable-1 > tbody > tr'):
    tr_split = tr.text.split('\n')
    nombre = tr_split[0]
    fcol,scol,tcol, = tr_split[1].split(' ')
    
    my_list.append([nombre,fcol,scol,tcol])
df = pd.DataFrame(my_list, columns=['nombre','1','x','2'])
```

Si mostramos el `dataframe`:

```
|nombre           |   1  |   x  |  2   |
---------------------------------------
|10Bet            | 2.45 | 3.20 | 2.70 |
|188BET           | 2.33 | 3.30 | 2.86 |
|1xBet            | 2.41 | 3.24 | 2.83 |
|888sport         | 2.38 | 3.15 | 2.95 |
|bet-at-home      | 2.36 | 3.13 | 2.88 |
|bet365           | 2.30 | 3.40 | 2.90 |
|Betclic          | 2.47 | 3.28 | 3.03 |
|Betfair          | 2.45 | 3.20 | 2.88 |
|Betsafe          | 2.36 | 3.25 | 2.90 |
|Betsson          | 2.35 | 3.25 | 2.90 |
|BetVictor        | 2.38 | 3.25 | 3.00 |
|Betway           | 2.40 | 3.20 | 2.90 |
|bwin             | 2.55 | 3.20 | 2.70 |
|ComeOn           | 2.50 | 3.25 | 2.80 |
|Interwetten      | 2.40 | 3.15 | 2.90 |
|Pinnacle         | 2.42 | 3.39 | 3.06 |
|SBOBET           | 2.35 | 3.10 | 3.00 |
|Unibet           | 2.40 | 3.20 | 3.00 |
|William Hill     | 2.35 | 3.25 | 3.00 |
|youwin           | 2.40 | 3.05 | 2.85 |
|Betfair Exchange | 2.43 | 3.33 | 3.04 |
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, ademas explicas el proceso que has seguido lo cual se agradece muchisimo ;)